# How to save content of TextField to plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios-simulator, plist

I want to save the content of TextFields in plist with corresponding Key-Values pair.
Like Password field should be saved with the Key-Password and Value-(entered in textField).

How can I do that?

and want to access it in some other class. Can I do it? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Stuff into `plist` is easy. Full working code follows which adds a persons contact info into a plist  -

```
// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

// set the variables to the values in the text fields
self.personName = nameEntered.text;
self.phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[phoneNumbers addObject:homePhone.text];
[phoneNumbers addObject:workPhone.text];
[phoneNumbers addObject:cellPhone.text];

// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personName, phoneNumbers, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Phones", nil]];

NSString *error = nil;
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

// check is plistData exists
if(plistData) 
{
    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
    [error release];
}
```

[[source]](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/)

Comment: hi, thanks.. but im not getting the location (place) where my plist is stored.. and library is not present in my local account.. what to do to search? i hav searched in Finder also..

Comment: i think they are somewhere in the subfolder here `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/ ` more here - http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/where-does-xcode-simulator-write-files.html

Comment: im not getting Library folder.. its showing the path but im not able to trace the given path..

Answer (score 0):

You can save the content of textField to Plist in the following manner :

```
        NSMutableDictionary *_plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
        [_plistDict setValue:textField.text forKey:@"Password"];
        [_plistDict writeToFile:pListPath atomically:YES];
```

If you want to retrieve that value from pList , You can use the following code :

```
NSMutableDictionary *_plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
    NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_plistDict objectForKey:@"Password"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Take a `NSMutableDictionary` add values of `UITextFeild` property of `text` in in keys of Dictionary. Like

```
         NSMutableDicitonary * dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dictionary setObject:textfield.text forKey:@"username"];
        [dictionary setObject:textfield.text forKey:@"password"];
```

Save Dictionary in plist and use it where ever it requires.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *aFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/plistName.plist", aDocumentsDirectory];

NSMutableArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aFilePath];


NSMutableDictionary *newComment = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newComment setValue:userName.text forKey:@"username"];
[newComment setValue:password.text forKey:@"password"];


[plistArray addObject:newComment];
[plistArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best practice** would be saving these info in NSUserDefaults instead of a plist. NSUserDefautls can be accessed from anywhere in your project.

Saving:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:[yourTextfield text] forKey:@"password"];
```

Retrieving:

```
 NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: It might be the best practice but how can we access NSUserDefaults in other classes? I tried by importing the class but it showing some error..

Comment: `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` is singleton so it can be accessed from anywhere in your app. You don't have to import anything. No need to pass the object between viewcontrollers. Save from one place and access from another place.

Comment: Did you simply copy pasted above code?if so, in above code `[yourTextfield text]` , here `yourTextfield` should be your declared textfield. Change that in your code.